# How do you pronounce $\tilde{R}$?

Tags: notation, pronunciation

I found $\tilde{R}$ in a mathematical text, and I would like to know how this is pronounced. I tried to search on the internet but was not able to find anything related.

Comment: I would go with "$R$ tilde" myself.

Comment: It's pronounced as "R tilde"

Comment: Say it how you want. I say "R-squiggle" or "R-tilde." There's no right or wrong way.

Comment: In Dutch it is sometimes pronounced "$R$ slang", meaning "$R$ snake" :-)

Comment: note: the answer unlike the above comments includes the possibility of tilde-R instead of just R-tilde

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That symbol on top is a [tilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde).

So you can pronounce that "arr tilde" or sometimes "tilde arr", depending on your preference. I've gotten used to "tilde arr" because that's how it's typed in LaTeX, namely \tilde R which when you put dollar signs around it, becomes $\tilde R$ (which, I see, is pretty much what you typed in your post).

Answer (score 3):

The symbol $\tilde{R}$ is also pronounced *arr twiddle*. We can hear it for instance in these *[lecture notes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbv3T15nWq0&t=328s)* by F. P. Schuller in minute 27 where he defines a *linear map* between vector spaces.